# Web.py : How to Post values from a multiple select in a form?Submit only gives me one of the selected values

Tags: python, html, web.py

Using Web.py :  How to Post values from a multiple select in a form?Submit only gives me one of the selected values.
Example code
Html code :

```
<form method="POST">
  <select name="primary[]"  id="primary" multiple="multiple">
      <option >a</option>
      <option >b</option>
      <option >c</option>
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

web.py/python code(only POST):

```
def POST(self):
    inp=web.input()
    s =inp['primary[]']
    print s
```

if I select both a and b the Output is only a.how to get all the values selected in POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add `[]` in html :

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="primary"  id="primary" multiple="multiple">
  <option >a</option>
  <option >b</option>
  <option >c</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and in web.py:

```
def POST(self):
    s = web.input(primary = [])
    print str(s.primary)
```

Comment: sorry I don't  get your point, insert what value to where ? @Rishin